# CSS floats and padding

Tags: css, padding, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create a 2 column box (33%/66%) with CSS, but I'm having problems with floats and padding. I want to house the icon and all text withing the containing box with 30px padding all round. The 'facttext' is not showing any padding to the left, even though it's set at 30px, is there any obvious reason why?

Code used is as follows:

Codepen: http://codepen.io/graemebryson/pen/mvBKs

On website (displays better): http://energy-hypermarket.org/test (@ bottom)

HTML

```
<div class="fact">
<div class="facticon">
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/fact.outline.png">
<h2>Did You Know?</h2>
</div>
<div class="facttext">
You could save up to 40% on your energy bills by simply upgrading your Boiler with Energy Hypermarket.
<a class="offerbutton" href="/boiler-package">Learn more</a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fact {
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
}

.facticon {
border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
float: left;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 30px 30px 0;
text-align: center;
width: 33%;
}

.facttext {
padding: 30px;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Sorry Pavlo, mean to ask the question about the padding after formatting the code but completely missed it - have now edited to include question at top @Pavlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats because your `facttext` is not floating, when you check your code in FireBug, you would see that the padding is added, but on a block level.

[image]

[See updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aFvcE) for a corrected padding version.

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that - thanks for the detailed answer Mark.

Answer (score 2):

CSS

```
.facttext {
    padding: 30px;
    float: right;     /* -- New -- */
    width: 66%;       /* -- New -- */
 }
```

This will give the right padding on the .facttext element.